# Setting automatic random password for wifi

Tags: random, sed, cron, passwords, wifi

I am trying to set up on my office "guest" wifi, something that gives me everyday a new password. I am doing it on a raspberry Pi.

i've come so far as to set up SED to do it manually :

" **sudo sed -i 's/wpa_passphrase=.* /wpa_passphrase=test_new_wifi/' /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf** "

and i found this other command here to do randomly generates passwords :

"  **< /dev/urandom tr -dc a-z0-9 | head -c6**  "

the big question is, is there a away i can put both together so later on i'll be able to set up cronjob, so i will generate a new password every day. ????

Sorry guys, i am still a noob in "the" area :D

Comment: i mean, to put "random password command" inside of the "sed" command

Answer (score 1):

```
PASSWD=$(tr -dc a-z0-9 < /dev/urandom | head -c6)
sudo sed -i "s/wpa_passphrase=.* /wpa_passphrase=$PASSWD/" /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```